# Can we deploy helix structure on azure appservice without using teamcity

Tags: azure, helix

My team is deploying `Sitecore 9.0.2` application to `azure appservice` for the first time since we got the project.

So while reading the ways to deploy the helix website we found that we will need to use Teamcity for it to run the gulp files.

I was wondering that is it possible to deploy the Sitecore helix website without using `TeamCity` by just using `Octopus` deploy. Does `Octopus` provide a way to run the `gulp` files to create the builds?

Because in the handover document provided by the last company doesn't contain any information about the `Teamcity`

Thank you

Comment: Your question is way more related to *Octopus Deploy using gulp tasks* than to Sitecore itself. You should take a look at those two articles: https://www.akshaysura.com/2016/12/27/finally-with-one-great-big-gulp-i-conquered-sitecore-helix/ and https://www.akshaysura.com/2016/12/28/helix-and-the-re-tooling-of-your-continuous-integration-and-deployments/

Comment: You don't _need_ TeamCity, Octo or gulp for that matter.  Helix is just a way of structuring your code - it's a regular ASP.NET website.  There are many other build and deploy models you can use.  Look into Azure DevOps as well as Googling `sitecore visual studio build` for a range of ways to achieve your task

Comment: Hi @RichardHauer thankyou but We were able to solve the issue and was able to successfully link the teamcity with octopus and creating the builds successfully

Answer (score 1):

No, Octopus Deploy cannot and should not be used to produce build artifacts.
It is designed to manage and deploy build artifacts that come from a variety of other systems. 
I would recommend that you look at building your solution using [Azure Devops Build Pipelines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/devops/pipelines/). It is very easy to configure and [connect to Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/azure-devops).

Comment: Hi @Mark thanx for your answer and sorry for late response  , We are not octopus for creating build artifacts we are just using it just for deploying, Teamcity is doing the job of creating the build artifacts.   Thankyou